# Is there a $3\times 3$ magic square adding up to $7$?

Tags: matrices, elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, magic-square

I suspect that there is no magic square with natural number entries (matrix where each row, column and long diagonal add up to the same number) which would add up to $7$. There is no restriction on which numbers have to appear in the slots, also the numbers that do appear are not resricted to single digit numbers, so 12 can appear in the magic square)

Is it correct? If yes, how can I prove it?

(I see there are quite a lot of questions about magic squares on the site, but I havent been able to find an exact duplicate.)

What follows is my attempt write a magic square adding up to 7.

2, 3,2 -
3,2,2 -
2,2,3 -

Comment: So magic square must has a 9 in the entry?

Comment: If your entries are positive integers, then this ain't gonna work...

Comment: @John: I dont follow. :-(

Comment: @imranfat: by not working, you mean there is no such magic square? if yes then I am interested in the proof of the fact...

Comment: hope I clarified my question enough

Comment: Well, $12$ can't appear because it's greater than $7$ and you only want natural number entries...

Comment: :-), yes I know, I meant in principle can appear...

Comment: maybe I shouldnt have used different label than magic square - in my version the entries do NOT have to be distinct

Comment: @Adam. It's next mornign here and I see that Ivan essentially laid out the proof. Bottom line: the sum of each row/column/diagonal has to add up to the same number which is to be a multiple of 3. I will put a magic square "generator" in the answer box

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Suppose we have a $3 \times 3$ magic square with integer entries, and each row/column/main diagonal adds to $n$:

$$\begin{pmatrix} a &b & c \\ d& e & f \\ g &h &i \end{pmatrix}$$

Then

\begin{align}
3n& =(a+b+c)+(d+e+f)+(g+h+i) \\
&=e+(a+i)+(b+h)+(c+g)+(d+f) \\
&=e+(n-e)+(n-e)+(n-e)+(n-e) \\
&=4n-3e
\end{align}

Thus $n=3e$ so $n$ must be a multiple of $3$. Unfortunately, $7$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Comment: @DanielRust By rearranging the terms

Comment: We dont seem to be using the fact that the entries are positive, so I guess Ivan Loh´s proof applies even to the case of arbitrary integers.

Comment: @Adam Note that even if one proves this result for positive entries, by adding the same huge positive integer to all entries you get it for all integers.

Answer (score 1):

I've just spent $5$ minutes trying all possible combinations for the central square from $7$ to $4$ and it's easy to see that none of these are possible central squares. I don't forsee there being much trouble in checking the elements $3$ to $0$ either, but the possible combinations of diagonal squares does get slightly larger for smaller values of the central - but not so large that $10$ minutes wouldn't be enough to check by hand.

Comment: The central square does seem to be the one, where the devil of the matter is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Adam (and others if interested). Here is a general 3by3 magic square generator. Draw a 3by 3 grid and write down the following in each box:
Top row: $x+y$ , $x-y-z$ , $x+z$, middle row: $x-y+z$ , $x$ , $x+y-z$ , bottom row: $x-z$ , $x+y+z$ , $x-y$ 
The sum of each row/column/diagonal is $3x$

Comment: What is x,y and z?

Comment: any real number you wish. Please note that the sum of each row/column or diagonal is the same, being 3x. It will always be a magic square!

Comment: Pretty neat. I wonder how you came up with it.